# Python Class vs. Instance Variable | Integer / List

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn the difference between class variables and **init** ones. I understand the class variables are usually static and can change.

I would like to know why when you print the Variable Accounts after it had been changed by the instance of Sam it has changed for David.

HOWEVER, whenever you update the balance for Sam, it does not change for David. Thank you.

```
class BankAccount:
    Balance = 0
    Accounts = []

Sam = BankAccount()
David = BankAccount()

print("Sam's Balance", Sam.Balance)
print("David's Balance", David.Balance)
print("")
print("Sam's Accounts", Sam.Accounts)
print("David's Accounts", David.Accounts)


Sam.Balance = 1000
Sam.Accounts.append("Sam's Personal Checking")

print("Sam's Balance", Sam.Balance)
print("David's Balance", David.Balance)
print("")
print("Sam's Accounts", Sam.Accounts)
print("David's Accounts", David.Accounts)
```

Comment: You are binding a new variable `Sam.Balance` that hides the `BankAccount.Balance` vs. `append()`ing to the existing list. Even with `Sam.Balance += 1000` would still hide `BankAccount.Balance` because `int`s are not mutable.

Comment: With `Sam.Balance=1000` you are creating new instance variable.

Comment: When I added a print function within the class to print The global Variable Balance and self.Balance they were the same though? I'm a bit confused about that part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To illustrate the answers given:  you can check to see if objects are the same thing using [id()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id) or the [is](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not) operator.

```
>>> class BankAccount:
    Balance = 0
    Accounts = []


>>> a = BankAccount()
>>> b = BankAccount()
>>> id(BankAccount.Balance), id(a.Balance), id(b.Balance)
(507102960, 507102960, 507102960)
>>> BankAccount.Balance is a.Balance is b.Balance
True
>>> BankAccount.Accounts is a.Accounts is b.Accounts
True
>>> b.Balance = 2
>>> id(BankAccount.Balance), id(a.Balance), id(b.Balance)
(507102960, 507102960, 507103024)
>>> BankAccount.Balance is a.Balance is b.Balance
False
>>> a.Accounts.append(2)
>>> BankAccount.Accounts is a.Accounts is b.Accounts
True
>>>
```

[Naming and Binding](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) is a good read.
And the [Classes section of the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#classes) may provide insight.

Comment: Thank you so much this is a wonderful example, haha it's quite difficult for me to wrap my head around the full difference. I've been trying to read a lot about the difference between knit and class Variable. @wwii

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you assign an attribute to an instance, it becomes an instance variable (not shared by any other instance), even if it was a class variable before.  This is what happened in the case of `Sam.Balance = 1000`.  However, `Sam.Accounts.append("Sam's Personal Checking")` is an entirely different situation - you did not assign anything, the Accounts list is exactly the same object as it was before, still a class variable.  You simply made a change to the contents of that list, which is visible no matter how you retrieve the list.

Answer (score 0):

Integer in Python is not mutable, so when `Sam.Balance = 1000`, this will add instance variable `Balance` to instance `Sam`, not change the class variable.

Comment: class BankAccount:
     Balance = 0
     def PrintSelf(self):
      try:
       print(self.Balance)
      except:
       print("I have nit found myself yet")
      print(Balance)
     
    Sam = BankAccount()
    Sam.Balance = 1000
    
    Sam.PrintSelf()

Comment: I'm on my iPad so return is automatically making me do that. Why in this code above does Balance == 1000 if it does not change the class variable? Thank you guys so much for the help!! @whbb